# gym env.seed() doesn't work anymore after some steps

Tags: python, random, random-seed, openai-gym

It seems when I do env.seed(x), it start in the same way, but after some episodes it start make differences.. why? Even if I add np.random.seed(0) with env.seed(0)

```py
import gym
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
env.seed(0)
n1 = []
for _ in range(1):
    n1.append(env.reset()[0])
    done = False
    while not done:
        next , reward, done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
        n1.append(next[0])
env.seed(0)
n2 = []
for _ in range(1):
    n2.append(env.reset()[0])
    done = False
    while not done:
        next , reward, done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
        n2.append(next[0])
print(n1[0] == n2[0]) # trueprint(n1[1] == n2[1]) # true
print(n1[2] == n2[2]) # sometimes true????
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the seed on the action space aswell as you are calling `sample`:

```
env.action_space.seed(seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `env.action_space.sample()` use `np.random.randint(0, 2)`